# Wordpress retrieve thumbnail in theme support

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I got this problem which my limited capabilities can´t handle. I tried to use the near solutions but does not work the way I expected.

In the post nav previous link I want to retrieve the thumbnail image link and text over the image and make the whole thing clickable and zoom in on it while hovering. Like in the end of http://swordandscale.com/sword-and-scale-episode-100/. But I only manage to get the text. Here is my function,

get_header(); ?>

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-1">

                    <?php 

                        if( have_posts() ):

                            while( have_posts() ): the_post();

                                sidekick_save_post_views( get_the_ID() );

                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/single', get_post_format() );





                                echo sidekick_post_navigation();



                                if ( comments_open() ):
                                    comments_template();
                                endif;

                            endwhile;

                        endif;

                    ?>


                </div><!-- .col-xs-12 -->

            </div><!-- .row -->
        </div><!-- .container -->


    </main>
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

```
/*
========================
    SINGLE POST CUSTOM FUNCTIONS
========================
```

*/
function sidekick_post_navigation(){

```
$nav = '<div class="row">';

$prev = get_previous_post_link( '<div class="post-link-nav">%link</div>', '%title' );
$nav .= '<div class="col-xs-12 text-center">' . $prev . '</div>';

$next = get_next_post_link( '<div class="post-link-nav">%link</div>', '%title' );
$nav .= '<div class="col-xs-12 text-center">' . $next . '</div>';

$nav .= '</div>';

return $nav;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is open your theme’s single.php file and add the following code inside the loop most likely after the_content() area:

```
<div id="cooler-nav" class="navigation">
<?php $prevPost = get_previous_post(true);
if($prevPost) {?>
<div class="nav-box previous">
 <?php $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(100,100) 
);?>
<?php previous_post_link('%link',"$prevthumbnail  <p>%title</p>", TRUE); ?>
</div>

<?php } $nextPost = get_next_post(true);
if($nextPost) { ?>
<div class="nav-box next" style="float:right;">
<?php $nextthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($nextPost->ID, array(100,100) ); 
} ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link',"$nextthumbnail  <p>%title</p>", TRUE); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div><!--#cooler-nav div -->
```

Next thing you need to do is open your style.css file and add the following styles:

```
#cooler-nav{clear: both; height: 100px; margin: 0 0 70px;}
#cooler-nav .nav-box{background: #e9e9e9; padding: 10px;}
#cooler-nav img{float: left; margin: 0 10px 0 0;}
#cooler-nav p{margin: 0 10px; font-size: 12px; vertical-align: middle;}
#cooler-nav .previous{float: left; vertical-align: middle; width: 250px; 
height: 100px;}
#cooler-nav .next{float: right; width: 250px;}
```

Feel free to change the styling to match it with your theme. Often our users like to style the code, so it makes it easier for them to tweak it. This is just basic styling which you should be able to customize easily.
If you want to change the thumbnail size, then simply change the array(100,100) to whatever you like.

hope that is usefull for you .

Comment: I got all my other commands in a file called theme-support.php and call the other stuff from them. Is there no way to call them in them and echo it from that file?

Comment: The code you posted Ive already tried at http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-use-thumbnails-with-previous-and-next-post-links-in-wordpress/   I wanted to know how I could implement it with the code above.

Comment: to understand well what you said , you want to do all this treatement in a function and call it in the single.php ??

Comment: Yes exactly, preferly in my sidekick_post_navigation. Because if I do it in my single.php. The functions breaks the php. I pasted my single.php for you above so you can see Mohammed.

Comment: what do you get as results when you try you own method ?

Comment: At the moment I only get the name of the previous & next  post which is clickable. And i wanted to add the thumbnail to thoose links from the posts.

Comment: just get the code above in my comment and try to append the code as you did in your own method . it's that easy . if you can't do it . give me untill this night. i will carry about it . i'm too busy now .

Comment: Yes I will look at it later tonight. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I tried to put $prevthumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(100,100) in my code and it shows up but it´s the thumbnail from the post im on not the previous. And also there comes an error.